# How to develop a drop-down menu in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex

How to develop a drop-down menu in Flex 3?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

[Menu control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=menucontrols_5.html) & [Defining menu structure and data](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=menucontrols_3.html)

[image]

UPDATED:

just change:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" 
        label="Open Menu" 
        click="createAndShow();"/>
```

to

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" 
        label="Open Menu" 
        mouseOver="createAndShow();"/>
```

Comment: thanks Adnan i want to do it on mouse in over not by click to appear the sub menu...

Comment: @Hari kanna just updated my answer. just change from click to mouseOver

Answer (score 0):

There is already one : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_5.html